# Qt hovering over child widgets, Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation not working

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a parent widget containing some child widgets. The problem I am facing is that when I hover over the child widgets, the parent widget is getting hovered too.

So I have gone through Qt's doc and it says in http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qhoverevent.html that [Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) is exactly what i need. But it's simply not working.

Here is a basic example

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class Label : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Label(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR) :
        QLabel("parent",parent),
        childLabel(new QLabel("child"))
    {
        this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
        childLabel->setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation); //<-not working
        childLabel->setObjectName("childLabel");
        auto hLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        hLayout->addWidget(childLabel,0,Qt::AlignRight);
        hLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
        setLayout(hLayout);
        setStyleSheet(R"(
                      QLabel:hover{background-color: blue;}
                      #childLabel:hover{ background-color: yellow;}
                      )");
    }
    ~Label() = default;
private:
    QLabel *childLabel;
};
```

Check it out and you will see that the parent is still hovered, when you hover the child... Am I missing here something or is Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation not working. Is there any workaround?

Thank you in advance

Best Regards!

Comment: "Hover" inside qss - is not a mouse event. It's a logical function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Ok, but isn't this hover function triggered by the hoverEvent ? So basically i want to avoid event propagation to parent. Which i checked here is kinda impossible.

Comment: Hard to say. You may put an event filter on main widget and on label and debug it, to be sure.

Comment: I did it already, it shows me exactly this event propagation from child to parent (hovering child hovers parent too).

Comment: Try to set your label to use native window, don't know... Maybe it will help. [`Qt::WA_NativeWindow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

Comment: Qt::WA_NativeWindow does not help :( . I'll do it directly with enterEvent now. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Np, you are welcome.